# Remote Blob Storage is installed and enabled but doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, remote-blob-storage, 2013

- i installed the RBS.msi.

  - my rbs tables are created in the sql sharepoint content database
  - and i performed the powershell commands.

im running SP2013 Foundation Preview with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on 2008 R2 Server unfortunately i had troubles down- / and uploading documents on my SP-Server.
I checked the log-files and saw that my rbs service did not have any EXECUTE permissions on some rbs databases. So i unattached my content DB from the RBS like this

```
$cdb=Get-SPContentDatabase <ContentDbName>

$rbs=$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings

$rbs.GetProviderNames()

$rbs.SetActiveProviderName("")
```

Afterwards i was able to upload documents again. Now that i have reattached my content database to the RBS i still can upload documents but the files are not stored inside of the rbs directory.. any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43010/file-size-too-large-with-rbs-and-sharepoint-2013 was the same issue.. apparently a bug in the preview

Comment: Myself I've installed and configure RBS (correctly) in Sharepoint 2013 but doesn't work.
It didn't put any file in File System (BLOB Storage). The rights seems to be ok.
Any idea why?
Other people seems to have the same issue:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e279451f-fe02-4e9f-8e97-30290bdbdc35/rbs-with-sharepoint-2013-and-sql-2012-almost-working?prof=required
Thanks
Grig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue.. i checked the user context which my sharepoint web application is running. i thought it was another user than it really was. so i checked the rights for this user on my DB... obviously there were none.. so i set them up and at least this error was solved.