# File size too large with RBS and SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, remote-blob-storage, rbs, 2013

since i set up my SP2013 Foundation Preview with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express i wanted to use the RemoteBlobStorage. It works seemingly fine just now.

The only problem is if my files which im uploading are exceeding around about ~15MB i'm getting an error. So i checked the logs and apparently my SQL command is too long. There are some statements wich are executed repeatedly, apparently depending on file size.
The following error messages state that

> "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in
>   this RPC request. The maximum is 2100."

Since i can't really raise the number of parameters which are accepted (which also wouldn't make much sense) im wondering how to get around this issue and which service creates this statement (sharepoint, rbs, sql server)?

Regards,
peter

Comment: I did the same thing today on a new VM with Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and SharePoint 2012 Foundation Preview. The same behaviour occured. So this looks like a bug from the preview version.

Comment: since your using everything in preview then why dont try SQL Server 2012  as well ;)

Comment: gonna try this next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in the preview version. Tested in a different environment, see comment